# Connecting a Set of Vertices into an optimally weighted graph

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, graph-algorithm, minimum-spanning-tree, traveling-salesman

This is essentially the problem of connecting n destinations with the minimal amount of road possible.

The input is a set of vertices (a,b, ... , n)

The weight of an edge between two vertices is easily calculated (example the cartesian distance between the two vertices)

I would like an algorithm that given a set of vertices in euclidian space, returns a set of edges that would constitute a connected graph and whose total weight of edges is as small as it could be.

**In graph language, this is the Minimum Spanning Tree of a Connected Graph.**

With brute force I would have:

1. Define all possible edges between all vertices - say you have n
   vertices, then you have n(n-1)/2 edges in the complete graph
2. A possible edge can be on or off (2 states)
3. Go through all possible edge on/off
   combinations: 2^(n(n-1)/2)!
4. Ignore all those that would not connect the
   graph
5. From the remaining combinations, find the one whose sum of
   edge weights is the smallest of all

I understand this is an NP-Hard problem. However, realistically for my application, I will **have a maximum of 11 vertices**. I would like to be able to solve this on a typical modern smart phone, or at the very least on a small server size.

As a second variation, I would like to obtain the same goal, with the restriction that each vertex is connected to a maximum of one other vertex. Essentially obtaining a single trace, starting from any point, and finishing at any other point, as long as the graph is connected. There is no need to go back to where you started. **In graph language, this is the Open Euclidian Traveling Salesman Problem.**

Some pseudocode algorithms would be much helpful.

Comment: What is open euklidian tsp? Could you mean minimum hamiltonian path?(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path)

Comment: @Phpdna Open meaning not a cycle. euclidian meaning in 2d space. see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem#Euclidean_TSP

Comment: Yes, I know. I showed you a solver. But is this not a minimum hamiltonian path? Minium is the length of the path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok for the first problem you have to build a [Minimum Spanning Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_spanning_tree). There are several algorithms to do so, [Prim](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prim%27s_algorithm) and [Kruskal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kruskal%27s_algorithm). But take a look also in the first link to the treatment for complete graphs that it is your case.

For the second problem, it becomes a little more complicated. The problem becomes an Open [Traveling Salesman Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem#Euclidean_TSP) (oTSP). Reading the previous link maybe focused on Euclidean and Asymmetric.

Regards

Comment: Yes the first part is definitely an MST. In fact it is a Euclidian MST (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_minimum_spanning_tree). And the second part is a Euclidian oTSP as you correctly identified it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybee you could try a [greedy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greedy_algorithm) algorithm:

```
1. Create a list sortedList that stores each pair of nodes i and j and is sorted by the 
   weight w(i,j).
2. Create a HashSet connectedNodes that is empty at the beginning
3. while (connectedNodes.size() < n)
     element := first element of sortedList
     if (connectedNodes.isEmpty())
       connectedNodes.put(element.nodeI);
       connectedNodes.put(element.nodeJ);
       delete element from sortedList
     else 
       for(element in sortedList) //start again with the first
         if(connectedNodes.get(element.nodeI) || connectedNodes.get(element.nodeJ))
           if(!(connectedNodes.get(element.nodeI) && connectedNodes.get(element.nodeJ)))
              //so it does not include already both nodes
              connectedNodes.put(element.nodeI);
              connectedNodes.put(element.nodeJ);
              delete element from sortedList
              break;
           else 
              continue;
```

So I explain step 3 a little bit:

You add as long nodes till all nodes are connected to one other. It is sure that the graph is connected, because you just add a node, if he has a connection to an other one already in the `connectedNodes` list.

So this algorithm is greedy what means, it does not make sure, that the solution is optimal. But it is a quite good approximation, because it always takes the shortest edge (because `sortedList` is sorted by the weight of the edge).

Yo don't get `duplicates` in `connectedNodes`, because it is a `HashSet`, which also make the runtime faster.

All in all the runtime should be O(n^2) for the sorting at the beginning and below its around O(n^3), because in worst case you run in every step through the whole list that has size of n^2 and you do it n times, because you add one element in each step.

But more likely is, that you find an element much faster than O(n^2), i think in most cases it is O(n).

Comment: If I'm not mistaken this solution is [Prim's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prim%27s_algorithm), please always make the necessary references

Comment: I'm not sure.. jut thought how I would do it. Maybee I had this one on the back of my head :D

Answer (score 0):

You can solve the travelsalesman problem and the hamilton path problem with the optimap tsp solver fron gebweb or a linear program solver. But the first question seems to ask for a minimum spanning tree maybe the question tag is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

For the first problem, there is an `O(n^2 * 2^n)` time algorithm. Basically, you can use [dynamic programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming) to reduce the search space. Let's say the set of all vertices is `V`, so the state space consists of all subsets of `V`, and the objective function `f(S)` is the minimum sum of weights of the edges connecting vertices in `S`. For each state `S`, you may enumerate over all edges `(u, v)` where `u` is in `S` and `v` is in `V - S`, and update `f(S + {v})`. After checking all possible states, the optimal answer is then `f(V)`.

Below is the sample code to illustrate the idea, but it is implemented in a backward approach.

```
const int n = 11;
int weight[n][n];
int f[1 << n];
for (int state = 0; state < (1 << n); ++state)
{
    int res = INF;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        if ((state & (1 << i)) == 0) continue;
        for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j)
        {
            if (j == i || (state & (1 << j)) == 0) continue;
            if (res > f[state - (1 << j)] + weight[i][j])
            {
                res = f[state - (1 << j)] + weight[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
    f[state] = res;
}
printf("%d\n", f[(1 << n) - 1]);
```

For the second problem, sorry I don't quite understand it. Maybe you should provide some examples?

Comment: Thanks for this. The second oart is the "Open Traveling Salesman Problem". I updated the question.